# Understanding a recurring android logcat error

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

After compiling my ROM, I'm getting a constant recurring SystemUI crash notification, right after booting into the OS.

I'm kinda hazy on the log generated, & not able to exactly trace the cause of error.
Can someone please help me understand it?

```
D/SystemUIService( 5810): loading: class com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar
D/SystemUIService( 5810): running: com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar@41cd3358
I/StatusBarManagerService( 2314): registerStatusBar bar=com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBar$Stub$Proxy@41cedcd8
W/ResourceType( 5810): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0d0068 (t=12 e=104) in package 0 (error -75)
D/AndroidRuntime( 5810): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 5810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41993a08)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.systemui.SystemUIService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #99: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2671)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:156)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5229)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #99: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:16465)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.makeStatusBarView(PhoneStatusBar.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addStatusBarWindow(PhoneStatusBar.java:2192)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.createAndAddWindows(PhoneStatusBar.java:2168)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.start(BaseStatusBar.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.start(PhoneStatusBar.java:349)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at com.android.systemui.SystemUIService.onCreate(SystemUIService.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2661)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        ... 30 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3340)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5810):        ... 33 more
W/ActivityManager( 2314): Process com.android.systemui has crashed too many times: killing!
```